# Flask CORS stopped allowing access to resources

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cors, flask-cors

Only few days back I didn't have to make any modifications to Flask-CORS extension I'm
using. Apparently I do now.

Console is giving me this error on POST request:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/blog/posts. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)`

one of my configs:

```
class BaseConfig:
    CORS_HEADERS = 'Content-Type'
    ...
    ...
```

`__init__.py`:

```
...
...
from flask_cors import CORS

cors = CORS()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(BaseConfig)
    
    cors.init_app(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
    ...
    ...
    return app
```

my blueprint:

```
from flask_cors import cross_origin
...
...

class MyClass(Resource):

    def get(self):
       ...
       ...

    @cross_origin()
    def post(self):
       ...
       ...
```

Few days back all I had to do is just initialize the extension and it did the rest. Now I'm getting error even with explicitly specifying that I'm allowing access from everywhere. Once this works I'll narrow it down to only one domain but this still throws an error.

I've tried to get some debug output with `logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG`

`127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2021 11:02:31] "OPTIONS /blog/posts HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Any advice ?

Comment: likely because you updated Chrome browser.

Comment: I don't use Chrome. I'm a Firefox user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), try to initialize it like this

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Also make sure to delete cache and all in your browser.

Comment: I've tried going with defaults before. That's why I posted here as what I found in the docs didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following snippet and, you don't need to use a decorator for CORS anymore. But be careful if you are using Nginx as reverse proxy, you have to add proper headers for Nginx too.

```
cors = CORS(flask_app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*", "allow_headers": "*", "expose_headers": "*"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just for reference for anyone fighting with those issues as well. I tried various options but none worked in Chrome.

Since it was just a small boilerplate app, I finally had success replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in my react app:

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/calculate')
```

with

```
const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/calculate')
```

After that it worked.